# Floating filters were grayed out when using enterprise version

Tags: ag-grid

Recently, we're using `ag-grid` in our project. Previously, we just used `ag-grid` community version to try. However, we want to have a try of the enterprise version. We import community and enterprise version at the same time as below:

```
"ag-grid-community": "^24.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.1.0",
```

All functions work fine, except only the floating filters were grayed.

Can we import `ag-grid-community` and `ag-grid-enterprise` in the same time? Or we should only import one of them?

And how to solve the problem that all floating filters were disabled if we can import both of those two modules?

The floating filters were disabled:

[image: The floating filters were disabled]

Comment: yes, you can import both, but only import `ag-grid-enterprise` if you need to use the enterprise level features. What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Problem we are experiencing is that the floating filters for columns were grayed(disabled)  for the input element, do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution from https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/#enabling-set-filters, the default set filters is grayed by design and we can change it to other filters then the input can be enabled.

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518883/react-ag-grid-row-auto-height-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

By applying filter option and filter type in column Definition we can able to enable gray color

**Column Definitions:**

```
const columnDefs = [
        { field: 'id', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', headerName: 'Name'},
        { field: 'calss', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', headerName: 'Class'},
        { field: 'name', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', headerName: 'Name'},
    ]
```

**Grid Options:**

```
const gridOptions = {
        defaultColDef: {
            editable: false,
            filter: true,
            // flex: 1,
            floatingFilter: true,
            floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true },
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            suppressColumnsToolPanel: false,
            suppressMenu: true
        },
        sideBar: {
            defaultToolPanel: '',
            toolPanels: [
                {
                    iconKey: 'columns',
                    id: 'columns',
                    labelDefault: 'Columns',
                    labelKey: 'columns',
                    toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
                    toolPanelParams: {
                        suppressPivotMode: true,
                        suppressPivots: true,
                        suppressRowGroups: true,
                        suppressValues: true
                    }
                },
            ],
        },
    }
```

**Grid:**

```
         <Grid
            columnDefs={accountMapper}
            rowData={accountdata}
            gridOptions={gridOptionsAccount}
          /></Grid>
```