# React ag-grid row auto height doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, multiline, ag-grid-react

I was trying to implement the row auto height feature described in the docs here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

However it seems to not be working in my case. What happens for me is that the text doesn't wrap at all and it just creates a single long line for each row.

I've tried adapting the code as best as I could to my own app, but maybe I missed something? I'll be thankful if you could take a look at my code and tell me if something is missing:

```
const defaultColDefProperties = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    floatingFilter: true,
    filter: true,
    wrapText: true,
    autoHeight: true,
  };

const columnDefinition = [{headerName: "Key", field: "Key"},
                          {headerName: "Value", field: "Value"}];

const ConfigurationDataGrid = (props) =>
{                                                                           
    const [gridRowData, setGridRowData] = useState([]);  
    const gridApi = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(async () =>
    {
      const getRowData = async () =>
      {
        let rowData = await WebApi.getRowData();     
        setGridRowData(rowData);   
      }
      await getRowData();
    },[]);

    const onGridReady = params => 
    {
      gridApi.current = params.api;
    }

    const onColumnResized = (params) => 
    {
      params.api.resetRowHeights();
    }
  
    const onColumnVisible = (params) => 
    {
      params.api.resetRowHeights();
    }

    return (
          <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
              <UxDataGrid 
                id='datagrid' 
                className='custom-datagrid' 
                onGridReady={onGridReady}
                columnDefs={columnDefinition} 
                rowData={gridRowData} 
                defaultColDef={defaultColDefProperties}
                onColumnResized={onColumnResized}
                onColumnVisible={onColumnVisible}/>
          </div>
  );
}
```

The css class:

```
    .custom-datagrid {
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i don't see `AgGridReact` component used from where you have imported `UxDataGrid` component & can you share [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.).

Comment: I tried to reproduce  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-mwl1zr?file=index.js , but unable to reproduce it. is UxDataGrid is a component wrapper on top of AgGrid, if yes, please share the code and please share the  CSS class 'custom-datagrid' also.

Comment: @Chandan this UxDataGrid is a wrapper for ag-grid. I did not make it and I don't have its code. Just think of it as a regular ag-grid

Comment: @Sam I have added the css class. I don't have access to the UxDataGrid class which is like you said a wrapper for the ag-grid

Comment: @YonatanNir Thank you for the quick response. As per my experience, it looks defaultColDef is being passed to the underlying AG grid. you need to check the UXGrid documentation, how you need to pass this information. May be through gridOption property.(https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/)

Comment: @YonatanNir can you add output to your question.

Comment: @Sam the grid definition is passed as the grid does render with the columns and rows i want. It's just the height which does not change

Comment: @Chandan I just get a long single line rows. When the row doesn't fit the screen it adds 3 dots in the end (...) and the only way I can see the rest is by either resizing the column or by double clicking the row and dragging the mouse to the right while holding the left mouse key pressed

Comment: @YonatanNir There are two ways we can change the ag-grid row height either through props or through column API, is your onColumnResized is being called? , can you please put console.log see, is it possible to share your screen(team viewer or Webex)?

Comment: @Sam I have added a console log to both onColumnResized and onColumnVisible but only onColumnResized was called

Comment: Which is good. Did you tried calling colapi reset height function?

Comment: @Sam isn't that what I've done in my code listed in the question?

Comment: hmm, I see that, let me know if you can share your screen? it will be easier

Comment: @YonatanNir try adding `maxWith` in `columnDefs`

Comment: @Chandan That made the columns have a shorter width like I set it, but the text won't wrap and the height of the row remains as a single line row

Comment: @YonatanNir it is working on my side can you create example from you code instead

Comment: @Chandan The code is in the question..

Comment: @YonatanNir it does not contain what you have done in your wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I have `ra-ui-grid` it is the same as your component - `UxDataGrid`

Inside `ra-ui-grid` I have next definitions:

.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-balham grid"
    ...
></ag-grid-angular>
```

.ts:

```
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            ...
        },
```

.scss:

```
    ra-ui-grid {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;


        .grid {
            height: 100%;
         }
}
```

Then in some component, I am using ra-ui-grid with 2 wrappers

.html

```
    <div class="io">
        <div class="io__table">
            <ra-ui-grid
                [data]="data"
                [config]="gridConfig"
                [columns]="columnDefs"
                (onPaginationChanged)="paginationChanged.next($event)"
            ></ra-ui-grid>
        </div>
</div>
```

.scss:

```
        .io {
            height: calc(100% - 36px);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;

            &__table {
                flex: 1;
                min-height: 254px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: it was indeed the container itself the UxDataGrid  and not the code i made